# Failing installing R Docker on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: r, docker

Just tried to install the latest R  on Docker with a vanilla Ubuntu 22.04 and I`m getting the following error at the apt install step:

```
$ apt-get install -y r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.3.3-1.2204.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.3.3-1.2204.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've installed the previous R version using the following Dockerfile with no problem in the past. Any clue what's cooking with the latest R version? Here's my Dockerile that I have been using for many years to start my R projects in Docker.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

USER root

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

## INSTALL R
RUN apt update -y \
  && apt upgrade -y \
  && apt install -y \
  software-properties-common \
  dirmngr \
  gnupg2 \
  wget

RUN wget -qO- https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/marutter_pubkey.asc \
  | tee -a /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc \
  && add-apt-repository -y "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/" \
  && apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y r-base
```

**EDITS AFTER INITAL POST**

Ok... running the Dockerfile without the `apt-get install -y r-base` step allows me to look at the dependency tree of `r-core` within the docker container. For some reason, it seems that the latest `r-core-base` from the CRAN repo is not in the apt tree... Only the LTS version of the package is available, even though I get the CRAN when I look at the `r-base` policy...

**r-base-core**

```
$ apt policy r-base-core
r-base-core:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.1.2-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     4.1.2-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/universe arm64 Packages
```

**r-base**

```
$ apt policy r-base     
r-base:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.3.3-1.2204.0
  Version table:
     4.3.3-1.2204.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ Packages
     4.3.2-1.2204.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ Packages
     4.3.1-4.2204.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ Packages
     4.3.1-3.2204.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ Packages
     4.3.1-2.2204.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ Packages
     4.3.1-1.2204.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ Packages
     4.3.0-1.2204.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ Packages
     4.2.3-1.2204.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ Packages
     4.2.2.20221110-1.2204.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ Packages
     4.2.2-1.2204.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ Packages
     4.2.1-3.2204.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ Packages
     4.2.1-2.2204.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ Packages
     4.2.1-1.2204.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ Packages
     4.2.0-1.2204.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.2-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/universe arm64 Packages
```

Something is not right, right?

Comment: I think you may just have had a network outage. I can run all the steps fine.  Note that there are better base containers with these steps. I think the Rocker Project has one called `r-ubuntu` and then there is also `r2u` which does all you do here -- and add 22k binaries off CRAN.  See https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/ for details.

Comment: Ok, it's has if the latest `r-base-core` package is not accessible on the `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/` repo. Looking at the package policy:

`# apt policy r-base-core
r-base-core:
  Installed: 4.1.2-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 4.1.2-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 4.1.2-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/universe arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status'

Comment: Hmm, ok, strange. For some reason it seems like the `r-core-base` from Cran is not accessible (could be a network outage...). 

I'm using a vanilla because I need to add additional software with very specific version later. Thanks for the comment, I'll look at the other projects to check for compatibility.

Comment: The package is called `r-base-core`.  It is the same file at the Rutter PPA and at CRAN as CRAN mirrors it.  Maybe you don't have the security key set up for the CRAN repo in your Dockerfile.  This works for lots of other people and lots of CI runs.  I can also only reitertate that if you have trouble writing a Dockerfile, and working containers with this (and, in the case of r2u. much much more) why not use them and / or study their Dockerfiles?

Comment: You may want to edit this post. There is _false and misleading info_ ("omg rocker does not install") above that should be removed.  It is also uincommon to have _two answers_ by the original poster.  Maybe consolidate to one.  It would also be polite to mention (and link to) the cross-post and thread to the mailing list where you got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to @ada-lovelace, looking at the *Rocket Project*, I found a solution. However, I'm not sure what is causing the issues at the base...

Couple of clues:

1. When I follow the CRAN steps in a Vanilla Ubuntu instance in us-west-1 everything is working
2. Running the same steps in a 22.04 Docker image, it breaks at the install steps (Someone could confirm this, not sure how @ada-lovelace ran the steps exactly...)
3. Looking at the *Rocket Project* they set their apt repo differently, they add `ppa:marutter/rrutter4.0` instead of the CRAN `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/`

Here is a working version replacing the 'deb' entry from CRAN with a 'ppa:' entry from *Rocket Project* pointing to Michael Rutter repos. Something definetly change that I can't put my finger on as it use to work with the CRAN repos.

Any suggestion what the issues are? Alternatively, CRAN could update/notify their users.

**Working DOCKERFILE**

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

USER root

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

## INSTALL R
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  software-properties-common \
  dirmngr \
  gnupg2 \
  wget 


RUN wget -qO- https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/marutter_pubkey.asc \
  | tee -a /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc \
  && add-apt-repository -y "ppa:marutter/rrutter4.0" \
  && apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y r-base
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael Rutter, I tracked down the base of the issues. I am building the docker image on top of an ARM based M1 Mac platform and the CRAN repo only has AMD64 and i386 built packages (while Micheal PPA as AMD based packages as well). Specifying the correct architecture at the docker build time solves the problem.

Good reminder that with Apple switches from Intel to M1, we need to start paying attention to hardware issues again!

**Basic Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

USER root

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

## INSTALL R
RUN apt update -y \
  && apt upgrade -y \
  && apt install -y \
  software-properties-common \
  dirmngr \
  gnupg2 \
  wget

RUN wget -qO- https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/marutter_pubkey.asc \
  | tee -a /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc \
  && add-apt-repository -y "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/" \
  && apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y r-base
```

**Docker Build Command**

```
docker build -t r-base --platform linux/amd64 .
```